# What is the cohomology of $\operatorname{Sym}^g$ of a genus $g$ surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Is there any paper that computes $H^*(\operatorname{Sym}^g(F_g); \mathbb{Z})$ or $H^*(\operatorname{Sym}^g(F_g); \mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Yes. See the paper of Macdonald "Symmetric products of an algebraic curve" (Topology 1 1962 319–343).

Comment: Thank you ulrich, I will have to go to the library to read it.  Does it treat Z coefficients?

Comment: The paper is (currently) freely available online: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938362900198

Comment: I believe the computation of homology with rational coefficients, i.e. modulo torsion, was done earlier by Zariski in his paper on "a topological proof of Riemann Roch".